# Way to single sign on between PHP, Python, Ruby applications

Tags: web-applications, web, single-sign-on

There are one project using Python Django, another stand alone project using PHP.  Both has it own user auth. module.  What would be a simple way to merge user management together?

We start to check open source solution as [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas), [cosign](http://weblogin.org/overview.shtml).  It's a real concern that both used in campus/university, and not sure it would be good for web applications.

To initiate single sign on (SSO) between legacy applications, and some in future would be developed in Ruby.  Who can suggest a good investment in SSO solution?  A clear API, ready for web application and not too high hardware requirements would be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using [rubycas server](http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/) - it's an implementation of Jasig's CAS in Ruby (a sinatra app). In my experience, it was easier to set up than Jasig's, and I found better clients for CAS than for SAML (though both are great solutions). It integrates out-of-the-box with ldap directories (including AD) and of course user records from a database.

Getting PHP apps to authenticate against a CAS server is easy with [phpCAS](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS), ruby/rails apps can use [rubyCas client](http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-client/), and though I haven't used it, [django-cas](https://bitbucket.org/cpcc/django-cas/overview) looks promising.

For legacy apps, or even just protected folders shared by Apache, you can also use the Apache module [mod_auth_cas](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/mod_auth_cas).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered deploying a federated identity infrastructure based on [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0)?
There are open source solutions to build it.

The first thing you need is to deploy an Identity Provider (IdP). [Install and configure simpleSAMLphp as an IdP](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp) and connect it to the auth source you want (ldap, database, etc)

Then you can connect your apps to the IdP through a Service Provider (SP). There are different SP solutions based on the language of the software that you want to connect.

PHP software could be connected using a native integration using simpleSAMLphp [deployed as a SP](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp), and [using its API](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp-api)

Python/django apps could be connected using [pysaml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysaml2) and [djangosaml2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangosaml2/)

Ruby software supports SAML thanks to the [ruby-saml](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-saml/)

Comment: Together with `dearlbry's` suggestion, I got a big picture.