# LDAP to SAML/REST proxy

Tags: rest, ldap, saml

We are doing a Cloud POC, we will have applications hosted in the cloud that can only talk LDAP. Is there any system/appliance/virtual directory in the cloud that can appear to be an LDAP server from the application side, and on the output side talk SAML/REST based over the Internet to talk to our SSO product that can authenticate users against our corporate LDAP, which is tucked inside our internal firewall?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy an Identity provider connected to the ldap. You can adopt CAS or SAML technology.

In that wikipedia entry you can check the differents products (commercial and free software):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML-based_products_and_services

Most of them support Ldap as the authentication source backend.

Also Take a look on this thread:
[Way to single sign on between PHP, Python, Ruby applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276242/way-to-single-sign-on-between-php-python-ruby-applications/13286721#13286721)

Comment: We already have SAML/REST acting as IDP, exposed to Internet over https (port 443). What I need is something on the application side to convert pure LDAP to SAML and back and transmit. There is no direct/VPN connection between application server and backend auth system. all traffic has to flow over Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The emerging [SCIM (System for Cross-domain Identity Management)](http://www.simplecloud.info/) protocol might make more sense for the use case you're illustrating.  It's intended to provide a simple REST API around an identity store so you can perform Create/Read/Update/Delete operatons.  What will be available could theoritically be controlled via some policy within a SCIM server to alloy your clients to essentially interact with the backend LDAP directory.

Many products are adopting the SCIM standard now, such as ones from Ping Identity, Salesforce and UnboundID.

Comment: I need some existing product names, so that I can test them. When SCIM becomes mainstream, we will look at it.

Comment: Have a look at UnboundID's products - based on your problem description it sounds like the closest fit.